# qmake: When setting QMAKE_CXX = clang++ qmake is using g++ for linking

Tags: linker, qmake, clang++

When using `QMAKE_CXX = clang++` to force use of clang on a system where both gcc and clang is installed, clang++ is used for compiling the `.cpp` files but g++ is used for the final linking. This makes problems when UBSAN is used since g++ does not know clang option `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`. How to force qmake to use clang for linking too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `QMAKE_LINK=clang++` in addition to what you have specified for `QMAKE_CXX`.